# App Store Rejection – App works in testing but not when sending to the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

Boy, this is frustrating.

I sent in my app to Apple after months and months of development.  It was quickly rejected due to the fact that they said it was unresponsive at the home screen.  Here is the screenshot they sent me:

[image: Screenshot from Apple]

Now, when I build the exact archive of the app that I sent them, I have no such issues:

[image: What I see]

The buttons were created in the storyboard file and were IBOutlets, but the highscore label that you see was created programmatically.  Is it possible that the storyboard file didn't upload properly? I have already messaged them in the resolution center about it and tried to submit it again to see if it would work next time, but I was wondering if anyone knew anything about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been an extremely long time, but I thought I'd say what was wrong in case anyone comes across this in the future.  Basically, I had created the buttons in Interface Builder but was re-instantiating them in viewDidLoad of my view controller.  Since IBOutlets are weak properties, they were thus being released.  Why that wasn't happening when I ran it on my computer, I have no idea.  Still puzzles me to this day.

Answer (score 1):

From above screenshot, I've understand something that issue **related with network error**. See, they were tested with flight mode. According to apple guidelines, it should be go on in home screen without much more delay. At least show an alert for this issue. Just test with this scenario, you will get this.

Comment: Hi @Mani, thanks for your quick answer.  Just to clarify, are you saying that I should test the app in airplane mode?

Comment: Exactly. Also switch off your wifi too. That's, test without network connection. If You didn't handle this scenario, mostly happen this type of issue.

Comment: I tried running with no connection, but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: You should be sure your application is never stuck and it´s always giving a response to the user, if not, your application will be rejected. Try in different scenarios, with connection, no connection, connect and disconnect, and verify everytime the application is working in the way it has to. If not, it will be rejected again. It seems, like they have disconnected the device from internet in some particular case or just by minimizing the app, turn airplane on and then go again to the app and this has happened. Take a look and verify it

Comment: The buttons are in no way connected to the internet. Turning off or on the internet has no effect that I can find.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact they seem to have run the app on an iPad? Try running the app on the iPad simulator and seeing if the error occurs?

Comment: Nope, the buttons still show up on the iPad @KeithKennedy

Answer (score 1):

When they said it was unresponsive, it may be due to the fact that its stuck for certain reasons, check if you make any API call at the viewLoad method, also, if the UI may turn unresponsive incase you are performing some heavy operation on the main thread, try using a background thread of these operations

Comment: Thanks! I used a background thread in a few places and I'm hoping it doesn't get rejected this time!